# Render a RealTime Clock after append in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried many ways to make a live clock (with seconds) appear in a rendered table but it's not working propperly. The clock stays static, not showing second by second. I'm doing the following :

```
function myTable(){
    var table = $('<table></table>');
    table.append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')
            .addClass('col2 data')
            .attr('rowspan', '2')
            .append($('<span>')
                    .attr('id', 'date_time')
                )
        )
    )                   
    $("#myDiv").html(table)
}

liveClock();


var liveClock = function () {

    date = new Date;
    //some logic here to generate the data I need the result above ( no problems here )

    result = '' + d + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s;

    var setDateTime = function() {
        $("#date_time").html(result);
        return false;    
    };
    var everySec = setInterval(setDateTime, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're never updating `result`, so each time your code fires `SetDateTime`, it renders the same date in the table. Move these lines:

```
date = new Date;
//some logic here to generate the data I need the result above ( no problems here )

result = '' + d + '/' + month + '/' + year + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
```

Into your `setDateTime` function.